# jQuery time select function will not allow options in the dropdown to be selected

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

**EDIT 2 and ANSWER**

Ok, so I will explain how I ended up resolving this in case anyone else runs into a problem like this.

jQuery('body').delegate(jQuery('input:radio[name=shipping_method]:checked'), 'change', function () {

jQuery's delegate function takes arguments 'selector'>"string", 'eventType'>"string", 'handler'>"function".

My first argument was being taken as a jQuery element, rather than a string that it required. Maybe jQuery's error handler was somehow parsing that to a string, and was causing any change to any element within that div to cause a callback to the ('input:radio...) and thereby calling the buildTimeSelect() function and totally confusing me!

So ultimately, all I had to do was change jQuery('input:radio...) to simply 'input:radio...

HOPE SOMEONE FINDS THIS INFO USEFUL!

---

**EDIT**: after some more investigation, whats causing this is when a time is selected, a change is triggering a call to the buildTimeSelect() function. In this function, .empty() is being called on the dropdown list immediately and so the data is "reset".

Is there any way to prevent this from happening so the data isn't reset? I know I can take the .empty() out, but then it will leave all of the other times in the drop down and it will just continue to grow.

Any suggestions?

---

I've written this bit of jQuery to create a 2 select boxes which display a range of days, and depending on what day is selected, a range of time.

Everything works great, the data populates the dropdowns, it is dynamic depending on what day is selected, except that when I try to select one of the options in the time select dropdown list, it will not allow me to select a time.

All the timestamps are there, but when I try and click on a specific time, it reverts back to the first option in the list.

```
jQuery.noConflict();

function toggleShippingCheck() {
    toggleDelivery(jQuery('input:radio[name=shipping_method]:checked').val());
}

function isShippingValueDelivery(shippingValue) {
    if (shippingValue == 'flatrate_flatrate' || shippingValue == 'shipping') {
        return true;
    }
}

function isShippingValuePickup(shippingValue) {

    if (shippingValue == 'freeshipping_freeshipping') {
        return true;
    }

}

function toggleDelivery(currentSelectedShipping) {
    if (isShippingValueDelivery(currentSelectedShipping)) {
        jQuery('#time-to-pickup').hide();
        jQuery('#time-to-delivery').show();
        jQuery('#future_shipping_options').show();
        jQuery('#future_order_pickup_times').hide();
        jQuery('#future_order_delivery_times').show();
    //show extra fee
    jQuery('#extra_fee_section').show();
} else if (isShippingValuePickup(currentSelectedShipping)) {
    jQuery('#time-to-delivery').hide();
    jQuery('#time-to-pickup').show();
    jQuery('#future_shipping_options').show();
    jQuery('#future_order_pickup_times').show();
    jQuery('#future_order_delivery_times').hide();

    //hide delivery extra fee
    jQuery('#extra_fee_section').hide();
}
}


jQuery(document).ready(function () {
jQuery('body').delegate('#future-order-day', 'change', function () {
    buildTimeSelect(jQuery(this).val());
});

jQuery('body').delegate(jQuery('input:radio[name=shipping_method]:checked'), 'change', function () {
    buildTimeSelect(jQuery('#future-order-day').val());
});

function buildTimeSelect(epochTime) {

    var pickupJson = jQuery.parseJSON(jQuery('#pickup-times').text());
    var deliveryJson = jQuery.parseJSON(jQuery('#delivery-times').text());
    var selectJson;


    var shippingValue = jQuery('input:radio[name=shipping_method]:checked').val();

    if (isShippingValueDelivery(shippingValue)){
        selectJson = deliveryJson;
    } else {
        selectJson = pickupJson;
    }

    //empty out time select
    jQuery('#future-order-time').empty();
    jQuery.each(selectJson.days, function (key, value) {
        if (value.epochTimeID == epochTime) {

            //with each time, populate it with values that match the epoch time
            jQuery.each(value.times, function (key, value) {
                jQuery('#future-order-time')
                    .append(jQuery("<option></option>")
                        .attr("value", value.epochTime)
                        .text(value.time));
            });
        }
    });

}

//when shipping method changes
jQuery('body').delegate('input[name="shipping_method"]:radio', 'change', function () {
    toggleDelivery(jQuery(this).val());
});

//select other amount radio when extra fee input is in focus
jQuery('body').delegate('#extra_fee_amount', 'focus', function () {
    jQuery('#percent_selected_other').prop('checked', true);
});

//if tip is set to none fill the input with 0
jQuery('body').delegate('input[name="percent_selected"]:radio', 'change', function () {
    if (jQuery(this).val() == 0) {
        jQuery('#extra_fee_amount').val(0);
    }
    });
});
```

jQuery('#future-order-time').empty(); is being called every single time that a new time is selected, and clearing/resetting the input. I can't figure out where to put the .empty() call so that it doesnt clear the input every time its selected.

Here is the corresponding HTML/PHP for the div id's

```
 <div id="future-order-section">
<div>
    <em><b>OR, you may select a future time:</b></em>
</div>

<?php if ($this->enableFutureOrder() == true): ?>
        <div id="future_shipping_options" style="display:none">
            <div id="future_order_pickup_times">
                Times available for future order pickup
                <!--Pickup JSON-->
                <p id="pickup-times" style="display:none"><?php echo $this->pickupTimesJSON(); ?></p>
            </div>
            <div id="future_order_delivery_times">
                Times available for future order delivery
                <!--Delivery JSON-->
            <p id="delivery-times" style="display:none"><?php echo $this->deliveryTimesJSON(); ?></p>
            </div>
            <div>
                <label>Select Date</label>
                <?php echo $this->buildHTMLSelectForPickupAndDeliveryDays(); ?>
            </div>
            <div>
                <label for="future-order-time">Select Time</label>
                <select id="future-order-time" class="future-order" name="future-order-time"></select>
            </div>
        </div>
<?php endif; ?>
</div>
```

Thanks for reading

Comment: Hi! Where is 'future-order-day' in the PHP/HTML code?

Comment: 'future-order-day" is created on the fly when the function is first called. It isn't displayed until on of the radio buttons is clicked.